# Conditional url building in rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, rest

I'm trying to build the a url like api/v1/mayors?gender=male in my api but I can't figure how to build the logic, here is index endpoint:

```
  def index
    mayors = Mayor.all
    if mayors.gender == 'male'
      males = mayors.male
      render json: { status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Prefeito/s carregado/s', data: males },
             status: :ok
    else
      females = mayors.female
      render json: { status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Prefeitas carregada/s', data: females },
             status: :ok
    end
  end
```

Here are the models

```
  scope :male, -> { where gender: 'male' }
  scope :female, -> { where gender: 'female' }
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Your first conditional should be: `if params[:gender] == 'male'`

Comment: I'm getting nothing in data

Comment: Do you have a public repo so I can take a look?

Comment: here we go: https://github.com/LeoFragozo/mayors-apis-refactor

Answer (score 0):

You may use the params to both build your url and use it into your controller :

To build the link into your view :

```
<%= link_to 'message of your link', routes_path(gender: 'male') %>
```

And to use the gender in your controller :
`params[:gender]`

For example :

```
if params[:gender] == 'male'
```

Comment: thanks fellow, but I don't have any views, it's a simple json api.